# How to execute adb command in Firebase Test Lab prior to a test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want to enable the logging of some tags during the testing.

How can I execute

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
```

on the firebase emulator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to execute arbitrary adb commands prior to a test in Firebase Test Lab.  Feel free to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to indicate what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executeShellCommand?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)

> Executes a shell command. This method returns a file descriptor that points to the standard output stream. The command execution is similar to running "adb shell " from a host connected to the device.

(Reference: https://github.com/Flank/flank/issues/1808)